# Read or Write from AT88SC1608 Memory card with dcic32.dll

Tags: c#, c++, smartcard, atmel, smartcard-reader

I'm trying to work with AT88SC1608 smart card with a card reader which works with dcic32.dll in a C# app

some functions like IC_CheckCard or IC_InitComm or IC_DevBeep works prefectly
but when read memory like below :

`IC_ReadConfigZone(int idComDev, short Offset, short len, byte[] RDataBuff);`

I don't know how it's work because related to this document([AT88SC1608 datasheet](https://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/83724/ATMEL/AT88SC1608/263/2/AT88SC1608.html)) - 4 bytes from 12 to 15 is for card code manufacture but when i try it for 3 different cards all values were same for example :

`RDataBuff = new byte[] { 126, 97, 164, 82}`

now I don't know how to use this data or
even write on a user zone or verify password ?
anyone can help or has experience ?

Answer (score 0):

Note: the AT88SC1608 is not a smart chip but a memory chip communicating via the two-wire protocol (not command APDUs according to ISO 7816-4) with similar capabilities as Infineon SLE44xx/SLE55xx, for which we have a couple of related questions here.

The reader may or may not support that kind of chip, but if it does, you have to check its documentation how the reading is supposed to work - most likely it will be some kind of APDUs too, but with 0xFF as first (i.e. CLA byte).

I note, that all the commands, which work in your set-up are commands handled by the reader itself, so no successful card communication took place yet, and what you get as response (in hex for easier reference: 7E 61 A4 52) is likely some kind of error code.